# Is there any way to connect database with visual studio that connection string may not be changed at the time of deployment

Tags: sql-server, database, string, connection

When I connect I have already my localhost connection string. I want to know that is there any way that I connect database to visual studio but i don't have to change connection string all the time during deployment.

Comment: Of course you have to change your connection strong on deployment - you're not supposed to be developing against your live database.

Comment: Visual studio publish has a mechanism that allows you to put the correct connection string in when publishing. And you often don't deploy such configuration because it's environment dependent. That said you haven't even explained what environment you are using, nor provided any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use transform file to do this. In your Solution Explore expand your `Web.config` file then you will see there are 2 files as

```
Web.Debug.config 
Web.Release.config
```

put your development configurations and connection string in `Web.Debug.config` and Deployment related configurations and connection string in to `Web.Release.config`

then it automatically pick the config file based on your build